# github webhook seem doesn't work with drone

Tags: docker, cicd, drone.io

I'm sure that the oAuth is valid, but it still doesn't work when I push the code.

Here are settings:
[image]

[image]

here are logs:
server:

```
{
  "acme": false,
  "host": "5685-220-136-43-106.ngrok-free.app",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "starting the http server",
  "port": ":80",
  "proto": "http",
  "time": "2023-04-13T11:54:15Z",
  "url": "http://5685-220-136-43-106.ngrok-free.app"
}
{
  "interval": "30m0s",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "starting the cron scheduler",
  "time": "2023-04-13T11:54:15Z"
}
{
  "interval": "24h0m0s",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "starting the zombie build reaper",
  "time": "2023-04-13T11:54:15Z"
}
```

Here say: starting the zombie build reaper, I think maybe is a problem, but I'm not sure

runner:

```
time="2023-04-13T11:54:15Z" level=info msg="successfully pinged the remote server"
time="2023-04-13T11:54:15Z" level=info msg="polling the remote server" arch=amd64 capacity=3 endpoint="http://drone-server" kind=pipeline os=linux type=docker
```

Drone url is generate by ngrok

And here is docker compose:

```
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:2
    container_name: drone-server
    volumes:
      - ./var/drone_server/:/var/lib/drone/
    environment:
      - DRONE_SERVER_HOST=${DRONE_SERVER_HOST}
      - DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=${DRONE_SERVER_PROTO}
      - DRONE_RPC_SECRET=${DRONE_RPC_SECRET}

      - DRONE_GITHUB_SERVER=https://github.com
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=${DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}
      - DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=${DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET}

      - DRONE_LOGS_PRETTY=true
      - DRONE_LOGS_COLOR=true
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
      
  drone-runner:
    image: drone/drone-runner-docker:1
    container_name: drone-runner
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DRONE_RPC_HOST=${DRONE_RPC_HOST}
      - DRONE_RPC_PROTO=${DRONE_RPC_PROTO}
      - DRONE_RPC_SECRET=${DRONE_RPC_SECRET}

      - DRONE_RUNNER_CAPACITY=3
    restart: always
```

.env file:

```
DRONE_SERVER_HOST=5685-220-136-43-106.ngrok-free.app
DRONE_SERVER_PROTO=http

DRONE_RPC_HOST=drone-server
DRONE_RPC_SECRET=5a9289b7d9676e80498738883e072b5c
DRONE_RPC_PROTO=http

DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=9ebf7416####1724ebd
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET=1f3d#####f52dfd9e8a51dc13873#####d3eb34
```

drone.yml:

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default

trigger:
  branch: 
    - master
  event: 
    - push

platform:
  os: linux
  arch: amd64

steps:
- name: build-image
  image: docker:latest
  commands:
  - docker build -t backendtest .
  - docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

Is there anything else I should set?